# How to correctly upload Laravel 5 application to server?

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to Laravel 5 and have realized that a lot has changed, I am more familiar with Laravel 4. I just tried uploading my site to a live VPS, I managed to change the URLs in `index.php` and `server.php` but I keep getting these errors:

[image: NetworkError:]

Which makes me believe there was something else I was supposed to change that I did not because these files are indeed there and my application works just fine on my localhost.

Also with the exception of my home page, the rest of the pages say not found when I click on their links.

This is my document structure:

[image: Document Structure]

**index.php**

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../*********/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../*********/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**server.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' and file_exists(__DIR__.'/../public_html'.$uri))
{
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/../public_html/index.php';
```

Comment: did you update the .env file ?? making sure you turn APP_DEBUG=false

Comment: No i did not, i will try that immediately.

Comment: Than you i did that and it worked, but now all my  pages except my homepage say Not Found when i click on them. Is there something else i need to change?

Comment: you are good to go, you might need to check your server log, and verify what is going on.

Comment: as a friendly reminder make sure you never ever forget to update .env

to 

APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false

before you bring them to live

Comment: So confused, this is the error i get in my error log for all my pages: File does not exist: /home/mytickf1/public_html/tickets

Comment: The /tickets is supposed to be a route not an actual file.

Comment: Okay it's looking like none of my routes are working, anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73797/discussion-between-terry-low-and-user3718908).

Comment: Solved by terry low.

Answer (score 2):

Following step you have must followed to move local to live server in Laravel.

1. Move all public folder data into root directory
2. In index.php change path to 
   require **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';   to   require **DIR**.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

   AND

   $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';  to  $app = require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/app.php';

   and set file permission to 744
3. In .htaccess file add following code after  RewriteEngine On.

   RewriteBase /
4. Change parameter in .env file.